# ObjectMapper removed fields without value during converting an object to dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

I used ObjectMapper to map JSON to object and vise versa, I want to convert an object to JSON, but when I try converting the object to JSON, the fields without value, will be deleted from JSON, for example:

```
class Provider: NSObject, Mappable {

    public var firstName:String?

    public var lastName:String?

    required init?(map: Map){

    }

    override init(){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.firstName <- map["firstName"]
        self.lastName <- map["lastName"]
}
```

When I call below function it prints a `JSON` without any key/value:

```
func printProviderJSON(){

    let provider = Provider()

    let providerDictionary = provider.toJSON()

    let datproviderData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: providerDictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)

    let providerJSON =  NSString(data: datproviderData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!

    print(providerJSON) // {}
}
```

But I need a JSON like this:

```
{
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It solved with one line in mapping function

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
        map.shouldIncludeNilValues = true
        self.firstName <- map["firstName"]
        self.lastName <- map["lastName"]
    }
```